# Determine if there exists a number in the array occurring k times

Tags: recursion, divide-and-conquer

I want to create a divide and conquer algorithm (O(nlgn) runtime) to determine if there exists a number in an array that occurs k times.  A constraint on this problem is that only a equality/inequality comparison method is defined on the objects of the array (i.e can't use <, >).

So I have tried a number of approaches including splitting the array into k pieces of equal size (approximately).  The approach is similar to finding the majority item in an array, however in the majority case when you split the array, you know that one half must have a majority item if such an item exists.  Any pointers or tips that one could provide to put me in the right direction ?

EDIT: To clear up a little, I am wondering whether the problem of finding the majority item by splitting the array in half and using a recursive solution can be extended to other situations where k may be n/4 or n/5 etc.

Maybe I should of phrased the question using n/k instead.

Comment: Is k an input or a fixed constant?

Comment: Also, do you know whether this is actually possible?

Comment: Who assigned this problem? What motivates it? Why do you believe it is possible?

Comment: We can assume k is a fixed constant.  i.e it could be n/4 (where n is the number of elements in Array)

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. As a simple example of why this is impossible, consider an input with a length-n array, all elements distinct, and k=2. The only way to be sure no element appears twice is to compare every element against every other element, which takes O(n^2) time. Until you perform all possible comparisons, you cannot be sure that some pair you didn't compare isn't actually equal.